# Approximating the "magic" tree rotation: P or NP?

Tags: co.combinatorics, binary-tree

Background. (tl;dr, skippable)

- "Dynamic" binary search trees are well researched.
- The "magic" rotation algorithm (="offline") knows the query sequence beforehand and thus uses a minimum of (costly) tree rotations. (Call the cost $C1$.)
- An "online" doesn't and thus is slower ($C2$). The ratio $r=C2/C1$ of such an algorithm is of utmost interest.
- The offline cost varies with the instance ($O(n)$ to $O(n\log n)$).
- Actually computing it *may* be NP-complete.
- For the general problem (queries may repeat) it *is* NP-complete. (Demaine)
- For a permutation query $\Pi$ (each item in the set $\{1\dots n\}$ is queried exactly once, an interesting subproblem) at least an $O(4^n)$ algorithm is known, so at least it can't get *worse* than NP. (Seidel)
- Speculation $\mathfrak S$: The subproblem is NP-complete too, but even an $r=O(1)$ approximation is in P and can be found in near $O(n)$ time. (Demaine, everyone else)
- A very good algorithm is "Greedy Future", which at least can implemented to run in $O(n^2)$ time, $r\ge 26/17$ but it is still open whether $r=O(1)$ holds for each instance. (My Master thesis :-)
- No $r=O(1)$ online algorithm is actually known. The attained $O(\log\log\log n)$ should be good enough for anyone, though :-)

I now present a heuristic, which is the basis (there are a number of snags, so a positive answer won't necessarily solve $\mathfrak S$, and I won't go into details) for a good approximation.

- Let $\Pi$ be an permutation of $\{1\dots n\}$ as above, $B$ be a binary string of length $n$ and $B'=\Pi(B)$ its permutation under $B$. Define a cost $C$ of any $B$ given some $\Pi$: For each adjacent pair of $0$s in $B$ add $1$ to $C$. For each adjacent pair of $1$s in $B'$ add $1$ to $C$. Given $P$, find the cheapest $P$.
- Since a "diamond of death" (pattern $0213\in P$) costs at least $1$ for *any* $B$, $B$ can have cost $O(n)$ (just repeat that pattern).
- Nevertheless, for a random $P$ $C$ tends to be extremely low. (At least for small $n$, that may change...)
- Task $\mathfrak T$: Given $\Pi$, find the $B$ with lowest cost $C$. Solutions where the numbers of $0$s and $1$s are about equal will be preferred. (Such a $B$, as said, with some fudgery applied, can be used as a very good approximation).

Question: Is $\mathfrak T$ NP-complete? (Meaning more or less: Do you offhandedly see a reduction scheme?)

Comment: Pedantic but important point: everywhere you say 'in NP' I presume you mean to say 'NP-complete'. Unless I'm missing something obvious _all_ these problems are **in** NP, but that says nothing about their hardness except to bound it from above.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Pedantic point ceded, I edit it :-)